# Combine column data of two sheets based on formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

In Libre Office Calc (or Excel) What formula to use (in sheet 3) in order to combine data of sheet 1 and 2 based on the ID column?

*`Get the last name and style from sheet 2 based on ID column`*

**Sheet 1**

```
╔═════╦═══════╗
║ ID  ║ First ║
╠═════╬═══════╣
║ aaa ║ bob   ║
║ aaa ║ bob   ║
║ aaa ║ bob   ║
║ bbb ║ james ║
║ bbb ║ james ║
║ ccc ║ mary  ║
╚═════╩═══════╝
```

**Sheet 2**

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════╗
║ ID  ║  Last  ║ Style  ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════╣
║ aaa ║ Marley ║ Reggae ║
║ bbb ║ Brown  ║ Funk   ║
║ ccc ║ Hopkin ║ Folk   ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════╝
```

**Sheet 3 - Results**

```
╔═════╦═══════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ ID  ║ First ║ Last ║ Style ║
╠═════╬═══════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ aaa ║ bob   ║      ║       ║
║ aaa ║ bob   ║      ║       ║
║ aaa ║ bob   ║      ║       ║
║ bbb ║ james ║      ║       ║
║ bbb ║ james ║      ║       ║
║ ccc ║ mary  ║      ║       ║
╚═════╩═══════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it my self :)
The function is Vlookup()

**=VLOOKUP(A2,b.$A$2:$J$403,2,0 )**

*b* is the name I gave to *Sheet 2*